# JSF 2.2: catch click on link of dynamically included html file

Tags: html, jsf

I my JSF view I display a list of links. When the user clicks on the list of links, two HTML files are loaded into a ui:include element from the folder on the server that the clicked link points to.

E.g. clicking the link:

```
http://localhost:7474/project/folder1
```

Loads the `menu.html` file from that folder into a ui:insert element as well as a file called `cov.html` into another ui:insert.

The `menu.html` looks like this:

```
<ul id="menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  >
   <li class="menulink">
      <a href="files/one.html">ONE</a>
      <ul>
         <li class="menulink">
            <a href="files/two.html">TWO</a>
            <ul>
               <li class="menulink">
                  <a href="files/three.html">THREE</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on the link `<a href="files/one.html">ONE</a>` should load the file

```
http://localhost:7474/project/folder1/files/one.html
```

into the `ui:insert` where previously the file `cov.html` had been loaded into (thus, replace the `cov.html` file).
So any file pointed to by one of those links in the menu.html should be loaded into the `ui:insert`.

When I click on one of the links now, it looks for the file:

```
http://localhost:7474/project/files/one.html
```

How can I get the value of the link that was clicked in my backing bean and load the correct file into the `ui:insert`?

Not an option for me would be to put the name of the folder into the link of the menu.html file, e.g. I cannot do this:

```
<a href="folder1/files/one.html">ONE</a>
```

because the files get uploaded by users in a zip folder and I want them to be able to name that folder anything they like. So I cannot hardcord that folder name in the `menu.html`.

Do the `a` elements need to have an attribute that the backing bean can access or could I somehow incerpect the requestes URL and correct it?

What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried with a `h:commandLink` instead of plain `a`? You could then perform a redirection to whatever you want from the managed bean.

Comment: Right, that would be an idea, I would then have to instruct the users to change the markup in the menu, which wouldn't be much of a problem... But just to be sure: Any other way of achieving this?

Comment: @XtremeBiker I see one problem though: Wouldn't that force the users to put the name of the backing bean on the command link in the action attribute?